# Reproducing a function as a Fermi distribution

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series, exponential-function, physics

I have a function such as

$$ g(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ 1 - \frac{\epsilon - \mu}{\sqrt{(\epsilon - \mu)^2 + \Delta^2}}\right]. $$

When $\Delta \rightarrow 0$, $g(\epsilon)$ reproduces very well the Fermi-Dirac distribution graphically

$$ f(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{e^{(\epsilon - \mu)/kT} + 1}$$

for $T \rightarrow 0$ (which is approximately the step function at this regime).

I have tried to expand $g(\epsilon)$ in order to arrive in $f(\epsilon)$ without success. Is there a possibility find $f(\epsilon)$ from $g(\epsilon)$ analytically?

Comment: In the given limits, both are functions are small but positive if $\epsilon>\mu$, $\tfrac12$ if $\epsilon=\mu$ or almost $1$ if $\epsilon<\mu$.

Comment: Yes Cosmas, I really appreciated the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might well be envisioning the wrong asymptotic. W.l.o.g., take $\Delta=kT$.
Both functions *g* and *f* are really functions of just *one variable*,
$$
x\equiv \frac{\Delta}{\epsilon-\mu },\\
g= G(x) = {1\over 2} \left ( 1-{1\over \sqrt{1+x^2} } \right ), \\
f=F(x)= {1\over e^{1/x} +1} ~~ .
$$

You wish to investigate the function
$$
H(x)=G(x) - F(x),
$$
which, as @J.G. reminded you, goes to 0 for the "majority" cases $|x|\ll 1$,
(i.e. *both*  $x>0$, $G(x)\to 0; ~~F(x)\to 0$, *and also* $x<0$, $G(x)\to 1; ~~F(x)\to 1$ ); and also the "transitional" ones $|x|\gg 1$, $G(x)\to 1/2; ~~F(x)\to 1/2$.

The only place where it does not vanish, e.g. $H(1)\approx -0.12$, is in the region $x=O(1)$, where no violent behavior is observed—recall   the transitional region $|x|\gg 1$ is $O(x^{-1})$ safe!

All you are reassured about is the cases where you actually *use* the approximation, $|x|\ll 1$, which cannot fail to work, $H(\pm 0.01)\approx 0.003\%$.

Comment: In particular, if $|x|$ is large then $F\approx\frac{1}{2+1/x}\approx\frac12-\frac{1}{4x}$ and $G\sim\frac12-\frac{1}{2|x|}$, but if $|x|$ is small then $G\sim\frac14x^2$ is small and $F$ admits the approximation $e^{-1/x}$ ($1-e^{-1/x}$) when $x>0$ ($x<0$).